# Unit Tests of Node.js REST services with Mocha or Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, jasmine, mocha.js

I have node module that exports REST methods for express.js (index, show, update, delete)..

What is the best approach to test mocha or jasmine unit test framework?

How should I describe my test?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally use [api-easy](https://github.com/flatiron/api-easy), it's based on vows and request.
With this module you can easily test REST APIs.

Here an example:

```
 var APIeasy = require('api-easy'),
      assert = require('assert');

  var suite = APIeasy.describe('your/awesome/api');

  suite.discuss('When using your awesome API')
       .discuss('and your awesome resource')
       .use('localhost', 8080)
       .setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
       .post({ test: 'data' })
         .expect(200, { ok: true })
         .expect('should respond with x-test-header', function (err, res, body) {
           assert.include(res.headers, 'x-test-header');
         })
       .export(module);
```

Comment: You mean something like Chai (http://chaijs.com/) or Should.js (https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js) ? I didn't try it, but I would say yes.

Comment: `api-easy` uses `vows` [here](https://github.com/flatiron/api-easy/blob/master/lib/api-easy.js#L13). You run `api-easy` tests with `vows`. You can't run `api-easy` tests with any other tool.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request) to do HTTP request (or for calling REST API) painlessly. When response is available then in the callback you can do your assertions. For assertions you can use any assertion module that you like but I would suggest give [should.js module](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/) a try. It's fun to write the should statements.

Regarding choosing between mocha, jasmine, vows or any other testing framework. It does not matter which one you choose. Look at their API and select the framework you think will be productive for you and matches your thinking and coding style.

Comment: While this (i.e., using the request module) seems to work when the test runs from the command line using jasmine-node, I can't seem to get it to run using grunt-contrib-jasmine. Instead of calling "var request = require('http')", which does not work because these tests run within Jasmine's SpecRunner.html in the browser, what should I be calling?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to run tests using Jasmine in browser. I don't think request package can work both on browser and server. For browser may be you can use jquery for the calls

Comment: I just posted this [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/tommystanton/6590337) where I tested out Mocha and should, using request on a mocked server powered by journey.